# android - How to update and delete only one row in SQLite Database using where arguments?

Tags: android, sqlite

So I am trying to delete only one instance of values from my SQLite database using the where args of db.update and db.delete in my app but it seems to delete and update all the matching ones. I only want to update or delete one. How do I do it? I tried using cursors but my implementation seems wrong. Help?

```
public long updateData(String oldFood, String oldCalorie, String newFood, Float newCalorie, String newDate) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(helper.FOOD_COLUMN, newFood);
    contentValues.put(helper.CALORIE_COLUMN, newCalorie);
    contentValues.put(helper.DATE, newDate);
    String[] columns = {helper.UID, helper.FOOD_COLUMN, helper.CALORIE_COLUMN, helper.DATE};
    //long id = db.update(helper.TABLE_NAME, contentValues, helper.FOOD_COLUMN + " = ? AND " + helper.CALORIE_COLUMN + " = ?", new String[]{oldFood, oldCalorie});
    Cursor cursor = db.query(helper.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    Information current = new Information();
    int uidIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(helper.UID);
    int cid = cursor.getInt(uidIndex);
    int foodIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(helper.FOOD_COLUMN);
    int calorieIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(helper.CALORIE_COLUMN);
    float oldCalorieFloat = Float.parseFloat(oldCalorie);
    if (oldFood == cursor.getString(foodIndex) && oldCalorieFloat == cursor.getFloat(calorieIndex)) {
        long id = db.update(helper.TABLE_NAME, contentValues, helper.FOOD_COLUMN + " = ? AND " + helper.CALORIE_COLUMN + " = ?", new String[]{oldFood, oldCalorie});
        db.close();
        return id;
    }
    long id=0;
    return id;
}
```

Comment: And which one of the matching ones is the one you want to touch? Seems more like a database design issue than code issue.

Comment: The one with the same food name and calories. It will be edited by the user.

Comment: Show some example data and the desired result.

Comment: So the user clicks the edit on my RecyclerView, the program gets the old food and calories like 100 g of Rice and 135, then the user inputs new food and calories. The program finds the 100 g of Rice and 135 on the table and if it matches, updates it to the new input. However, it does that for all the matches instead of only just one.

Comment: So it seems you'd need to use tag your recyclerview items with database rowid or other row-specific identifier to uniquely identify them when editing or deleting.

Comment: I haven't thought of that. I'll try though. I'll get back to you.

Comment: Quick question tho. How do you think should I tag the recyclerview items so that it stays unique forever?